# api to be used as a function with more parameters

Tags: java, rest, post

I am working on java and I have 4 rest Apis, with paths "/deleteplanA", "/deleteplanB", "/deleteplanC", "/deleteall". 
For eg, the API to delete plan A is:

```
@POST
@Path("/deleteplanA")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response deletePlanA(@FormParam("user_id")String userId) {
Response response;
    if(Verify(userId)) {
         Enter code here
    } else {
         Enter code here
    }
return response;
}
```

Here verify is a function that returns boolean value based on which the plan is deleted or not deleted.

Now the issue is that since "/deleteall" API calls the functions deletePlanA, deletePlanB and deletePlanC, the function Verify(String) will be executed 3 times. Is there a way to prevent that?

I tried adding a boolean argument in the 3 functions, but those don't seem to work since the js code calls the api with only one argument. (I dont want to pass the verification value from js since i feel that it can be manipulated easily by the users)

Answer (score 0):

You should factor out the `Enter code here` into individual methods without the `Verify` step.  Then in each delete method you verify, then call the method that does not contain the `Verify` step

```
public Response deleteAll(@FormParam("user_id")String userId) {
    if (Verify(userId)) {
        deletePlanAHelper(...);
        deletePlanBHelper(...);
        deletePlanCHelper(...);
    } else {
        ...
    }
}

public Response deletePlanA(@FormParam("user_id")String userId) {
    if (Verify(userId)) {
        deletePlanAHelper(...);
    } else {
        ...
    }
}

private ReturnType deletePlanAHelper(Parameters...) {
    Enter code here
}
```